# Structure of a questionnare panel in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a questionnaire panel in javafx. I have a label with the question and three buttons for the answer. I have manage to put all of them together, however I am not sure how can I structure the whole thing. Furthermore in the sam BorderPane I want to add more questions. How can I do so?

```
    BorderPane questionaires = new BorderPane();
    questionaires.setTop(questionnairesPane);
    questionaires.setCenter(questionsPane);
//QUESTIONS Panel

    questionnairesPane = new GridPane();
    questionnairesPane.setHgap(0); 
    questionnairesPane.setVgap(0); 
    questionnairesPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 200));

    results = new MyTitles("Questionnaires");
    questionnairesPane.setStyle("-fx-font: 150 hamster;  -fx-text-fill: white;");
    questionnairesPane.add(results,1,1);

    questionsPane = new GridPane();
    questionsPane.setHgap(15); 
    questionsPane.setVgap(30); 
    questionsPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 50, 0, 80));



    SsubjectLabel = new Label("What was your affective response during the game?");
    SsubjectLabel.setPrefWidth(1000.0);
    SsubjectLabel.setPrefHeight(70.0);
    SsubjectLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 cornerstone; -fx-text-fill: black;");

    boredom = new Button("Boredom");
    boredom.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 cornerstone; -fx-text-fill: black;");
    boredom.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {

    });

    engagement = new Button("Boredom");
    engagement.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 cornerstone; -fx-text-fill: black;");
    engagement.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {

    });

    frustration = new Button("Boredom");
    frustration.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 cornerstone; -fx-text-fill: black;");
    frustration.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {

    });


    questions.add(SsubjectLabel,1,1);  
    questions.add(boredom,1,2); 
    questions.add(engagement,1,3); 
    questions.add(frustration,1,4); 
    questions.add(next,2,4);
```

The functinoality is corrent but how can I structure corrent all buttons, this is what I am struggle to do. My panel right now looks like the following pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the class where you made the layout you can have one method that accept as parameter a `Question` class.

`Question` class should have the actuall question,possible answers and the correct one.

When you want to change or go to previous or next you just call the method above(`changeQuestion(Question newOne);`)

This method will change the values of javaFX elements you use.So you will not create new FX elements everytime.

If you want to hold a lot of questions use an array and in the Class Question have a value answered if has been answered or not.

All the above as a simple idea.

> Edit

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm) about build-in Layouts and Alignment in javaFX

What you can do is:

```
  HBox box = new HBox();
  Button confirm = new Button();
  box.getChildren().add(confirm);
  borderPane.setBottom(box);
```

the confirm will go on left of the window.That is called alignment.

You can use method `setAlignment();` to change the positioning of `Hbox` and `Button`.

There are better approaches though.Go on a full tutorial about fxml and javaFX [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/).

Comment: can u give me a simply example of the panel?

Comment: You mean the ui?It is based on how you want it to be.If you want the user to be able to go on the next question only if he answered the current then your picture + one confirm button is ok.Although you can have arrows and user can navigate with them lets say on a range of 10 questions.Search for 'jquery carousel' examples to get some ideas.Watch some youtube videos about user interface .Use your imagination :)

Comment: Ok I just used a button to go to the next question. My question from the begniing was more a structure thing. How can the button be below the answer in one single row?